# dart How do you use a named parameter with a lambda

Tags: dart, lambda, named-parameters

I have a method callback

```dart
var _onFinished = void Function(bool wasUser);
```

I now want to assign a lambda to onFinished:

```dart
_onFinished = (wasUser) => print('wasUser $wasUser');
```

The problem is that i get a compile error:

A value of type 'void Function(bool)' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'void Function({wasUser: bool})'.

Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'void Function({wasUser: bool})'.

I can't find any doco on what the method signature should be for a lambda that takes a named parameter.

Comment: The same way you'd do it for a normal function; enclose the parameter name in curly braces: `_onFinished = ({bool wasUser}) => print(...);`.

Comment: And now you say it, its obvious :) Thanks.